# JQuery .Sortable revert moving a LI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am designing a Kanban using JQuery .Sortable as per the example [here](http://orangeloops.com/2016/07/how-to-create-a-kanban-board-with-jquery/).

Basically we generate some (ul) lists and we can drag list items between lists using JQuery .Sortable:

```
  $(function() {
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
      receive: function( event, ui ) {
        // Do something when a list item is dragged from one ul to another ul
      }
    }).disableSelection();
  });
```

I have been able to tie this up to my database and all seems to work fine.

I do however want to be able to apply some rules as to what list an item is allowed to be dragged to. I can do a quick call to the database to check if it is a valid move in the event generated on the .Sortable, but I cannot see how I can then enforce that rule so that the list item reverts back to its original list.

I hope this makes sense, or let me know if you need any more specific info on the setup as per the example in the link above.

Comment: For a quick start, you can save the index of the li's from the draggable and also from the droppable. And then if your db returns not to do the move, just revert using those indexes...

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer found eventually...

```
ui.sender.sortable("cancel");
```

This placed in the event function will stop the everything in its track and reverts the LI back to its previous location.